# Positioning DataTables elements with DOM option

Tags: r, shiny, datatables-1.10, dt

I can't correctly position the `l`ength changing and the `f`iltering input to the top-right and bottom-left respectively on my `DT::datatable` output in `shiny` using the `dom` option. Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

set.seed(2282018)
company <- data.frame(Company = letters[1:10], Sales = scales::dollar(runif(10, 200, 1230)), stringsAsFactors = F)

# UI ---- 
ui <- function(){

  fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(

      sidebarPanel(numericInput("nums", label = "Num Input", value = 1, min = 1, max = 10)),

      mainPanel(dataTableOutput("mytable"))

      )

  )

}

# server ----
server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(company, 
              caption = tags$caption("StackOverflow Example"), 
              filter = "none", 
              options = list(
                autoWidth = T, 
                pageLength = 10, 
                scrollCollapse = T, 
                dom = '<"right"l>t<"left"f>')
              )

  })

}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

As stated before, my goal is to move `l` to the top right and `f` to the bottom left.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Process

In the [DataTable DOM positioning reference](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html), there are examples of moving elements to top/bottom, but not left/right. I'm not sure if moving elements left/right is possible using just the `dom` option.

However, per this [question about moving the search box](https://m.datatables.net/forums/discussion/32210/can-i-move-the-search-box-to-the-left), you can move the elements left/right in three steps:

1. Make CSS classes

   `css <- HTML(".pull-left{float: left !important;}
                 .pull-right{float: right !important;}")`
2. Use javascript/jQuery to add the classes to your datatable

   `js <- HTML("$(function(){
           setTimeout(function(){
              $('.dataTables_filter').addClass('pull-left');
              $('.dataTables_length').addClass('pull-right');
              }, 200);
              });")`
3. Add the CSS and JS to the HTML header of your shiny app

   `fluidPage(
                   tags$head(tags$style(css),
                             tags$script(js)),
                   ...)`

---

### Full example

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

set.seed(2282018)
company <- data.frame(Company = letters[1:10], Sales = scales::dollar(runif(10, 200, 1230)), stringsAsFactors = F)

css <- HTML(".pull-left{float: left !important;}
            .pull-right{float: right !important;}")

js <- HTML("$(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
           $('.dataTables_filter').addClass('pull-left');
           $('.dataTables_length').addClass('pull-right');
           }, 200);
           });")

# UI ---- 
ui <- function(){

        fluidPage(
                tags$head(tags$style(css),
                          tags$script(js)),

                sidebarLayout(

                        sidebarPanel(numericInput("nums", label = "Num Input", value = 1, min = 1, max = 10)),

                        mainPanel(dataTableOutput("mytable"))
                )       
        )
}

# server ----
server <- function(input, output, session){

        output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
                datatable(company, 
                          caption = tags$caption("StackOverflow Example"), 
                          filter = "none", 
                          options = list(
                                  autoWidth = T, 
                                  pageLength = 10, 
                                  scrollCollapse = T, 
                                  dom = '<"top"l>t<"bottom"f>')
                )
        })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```