# Position DT search box to center of table

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, dt

I am having a hard time figuring out the code to position the search box from a DT table in a Shiny app to the middle. I'm using a DT extension package, called DTedit, to create my table. Here is some example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DTedit)

##### Create the shiny UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  h3('DTedit Template'),
  uiOutput('mycontacts')
)

##### Create the Shiny server
server <- function(input, output) {
  mydata <- data.frame(name = character(),
                       email = character(),
                       useR = factor(levels = c('Yes', 'No')),
                       notes = character(),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  ##### Callback functions.
  my.insert.callback <- function(data, row) {
    mydata <- rbind(data, mydata)
    return(mydata)
  }
  my.update.callback <- function(data, olddata, row) {
    mydata <- olddata
    mydata[row, ] <- data[row, ]
    return(mydata)
  }
  my.delete.callback <- function(data, row) {
    mydata <- mydata[-row,]
    return(mydata)
  }
  
  ##### Create the DTedit object
  DTedit::dtedit(input, output,
                 name = 'mycontacts',
                 thedata = mydata,
                 edit.cols = c('name', 'email', 'useR', 'notes'),
                 edit.label.cols = c('Name', 'Email Address', 'Are they an R user?', 'Additional notes'),
                 input.types = c(notes='textAreaInput'),
                 view.cols = c('name', 'email', 'useR'),
                 callback.update = my.update.callback,
                 callback.delete = my.delete.callback,
                 show.insert = FALSE,         
                 show.copy = FALSE)
}

##### Start the shiny app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Based on googling, I found this CSS to align the search box to the center:

```
div.dataTables_wrapper  div.dataTables_filter {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to insert this CSS into the table. `dtedit()` has `datatable.options` parameter, so I think I'd have to use this parameter somehow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the DataTables [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option. An example is here: [How to rearrange DataTables controls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66689689/12567365). This all assumes your `dtedit` does acutally use DataTables options, of course. There are examples of using these options with `dt` - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49035864/positioning-datatables-elements-with-dom-option) is one.

Comment: If you have a specific `dtedit` solution (and if it's not a duplicate answer) you are always welcome to [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), to help future visitors to this question.

Comment: I feel like I should use the `dom` options: `dtedit(data, datatable.options =  list(dom = XXX))`. Not sure what to put inside `dom` to center the Search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the CSS you found works. Here is how to include it:

```
css <- "
div.dataTables_wrapper  div.dataTables_filter {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(css))
  ),
  ......
```

The box is centered but only in the available space, so it is not "globally" centered because of the "Show" item:

[image]

If you want to remove the "Show" item, you can use the option `dom = "frtip"`. Or if you want to keep it but globally center the search box, use this CSS instead:

```
css <- "
div.dataTables_wrapper  div.dataTables_filter {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
"
```